# OpenStax dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I’m looking to design a dropdown menu similar to the one on the OpenStax website, specifically the sections that include “Subjects”, “Technology”, and “What We Do”. Here’s the link for reference: https://openstax.org.

I’ve made some progress in creating the anchors and other elements, but I’m having trouble with the actual implementation. Could someone provide some guidance on this matter?

html

```
<nav class="navbar1">
            <img src=".\Logo.png" alt="OpenStax logo" width="120px" height="30px" class="logo">
            <p class="navpara">Access. The future of education.</p>
            <div class="dropdownmenu">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropdownbtn">Subjects</button>
                <div id="mydropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="">All</a>
                    <a href="">Business</a>
                    <a href="">College Success</a>
                    <a href="">Humanities</a>
                    <a href="">Science</a>
                    <a href="">Social Sciences</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdownmenu">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropdownbtn">Technology</button>
                <div id="mydropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="">OpenStax Assignable</a>
                    <a href="">OpenStax Kinetic</a>
                    <a href="">OpenStax Technology Partners</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdownmenu">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropdownbtn">What We do</button>
                <div id="mydropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="">About us</a>
                    <a href="">Team</a>
                    <a href="">Research</a>
                    <a href="">K12 Books & Resources</a>
                    <a href="">Institutional Partnership</a>
                    <a href="">Technology Partnership</a>
                    <a href="">Webinars</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Button class="givebtn">Give</Button>
            <button class="loginbtn">Login</button>
        </nav>
```

Css

```
.navbar1 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background-color: white;
}
.logo {
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 60px;
}
.navpara {
    margin-right: 14rem;
}

.dropdownbtn {
    padding: 13px 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdownmenu {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {display:block;}

.givebtn {
    padding: 13px 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.loginbtn {
    padding: 13px 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Javascript

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mydropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropdownbtn')) {
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit this so you have a *definitively answerable* question.  "Can someone help me" is not answerable.  "I'm having trouble with the implementation" is not actionable for anyone who could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go brother, hope this is what you need. A fully responsive and working navigation bar that looks exactly like the OpenStax one<3 
The code isn't the cleanest as I used your code and then started further fixing/making it. But you'll be able to understand it surely.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>OpenStax</title>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <section class="nav left">
        <img
          src="https://openstax.org/dist/images/logo.svg"
          alt="OpenStax logo"
          width="120px"
          height="30px"
          class="logo"
        />
        <p class="navpara">Access. The future of education.</p>
      </section>
      <section class="nav right">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropdownbtn">Subjects</button>
          <div id="mydropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="">All</a>
            <a href="">Business</a>
            <a href="">College Success</a>
            <a href="">Humanities</a>
            <a href="">Science</a>
            <a href="">Social Sciences</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropdownbtn">Technology</button>
          <div id="mydropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="">OpenStax Assignable</a>
            <a href="">OpenStax Kinetic</a>
            <a href="">OpenStax Technology Partners</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropdownbtn">What We do</button>
          <div id="mydropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="">About us</a>
            <a href="">Team</a>
            <a href="">Research</a>
            <a href="">K12 Books & Resources</a>
            <a href="">Institutional Partnership</a>
            <a href="">Technology Partnership</a>
            <a href="">Webinars</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="givebtn">Give</button>
        <button class="loginbtn dropdownbtn">Login</button>
      </section>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body,
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 50px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 5px #00000025;
  max-height: 60px;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav.left {
  gap: 1em;
}

.navpara {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 14rem;
}

.dropdownbtn {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdownbtn {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 2em;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 0px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #5e6162;
}

.dropdown:last-of-type .dropdownbtn {
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 20px 1em;
  width: 160px;
}

.dropdownbtn::after {
  content: " \25bc";
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0.8, 0.6);
  margin-left: 7px;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdownmenu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  border-top: 3px solid #72a648;
}

.dropdown.active .dropdown-content {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

/* Dropdown Links */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.givebtn {
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 0.4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 2rem;
  color: #424242;
  background-color: #fdbd3e;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 70.0625em) {
  .navbar {
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px 5px #00000025;
    min-height: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    gap: 0;
  }
  .navpara {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* I could've had made the hamburger in a better way, but it is just a placeholder */

@media (max-width: 45.0625em) {
  .navpara,
  .nav.right {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav.left::after {
    --clr: #afafaf;
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    width: 25px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: linear-gradient(
      0deg,
      var(--clr) 0%,
      var(--clr) 20%,
      transparent 20%,
      transparent 40%,
      var(--clr) 40%,
      var(--clr) 60%,
      transparent 60%,
      transparent 80%,
      var(--clr) 80%,
      var(--clr) 100%
    );
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .nav.left:hover::after {
    --clr: #010101;
  }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
let dropdown = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");

dropdown.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    el.classList.add("active");
  });
  el.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    el.classList.remove("active");
  });
});
```

Here's are screenshots of the navigation bar:
[image: OpenStax Nav]

[image: OpenStax Responsive Nav]